# Magento2: Default to sort by price descending not ascending

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, xml

Ok so I have my categories sorting by price. **Magento 2** defaults this to price ascending. But I would prefer it to be by price descending.

Pretty sure I can do this by customising `catalog_category_view.xml` in my theme and putting an argument to `product_list_toolbar` but I just can't quite figure it out. Any help?

Comment: use these two links https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1095 and https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1087/2. it will help you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Copy the file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

to

> app/design/frontend/{{Vender_Namespace}}/{{Theme_Name}}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

into your theme and add this to the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="category.view.container" destination="content" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

The links that Manashvi point to the right locations in the core for the files that control this functionality, but they don't provide a solution. I didn't find this anywhere in the core code so i just took a guess based on the code in this file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

and used the syntax in other configuration in other .xml files.

I did try calling `$block->setDefaultDirection('desc')` in the file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml

file but this didn't work. I haven't tracked down why, but using the xml to set the default worked, so i just moved on.

Comment: Just a quick question @circlesix your solution works great, but I'd like to apply it to only a couple of categories. I thought I'd be able to drop in the referenceContainer section in to Custom Layout Update section for each category within the admin panel but this has no affect. Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't figured out a solution yet, i'll post here when i can come up with a better way to do this.

Comment: @user1837290, you can just put the chunk starting and ending with `referenceContainer` in the "Layout Update XML" field in the admin of your specific categories.  As long as you aren't overriding the sorting globally in your theme it should work.  Related: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/167048/2415

Comment: @circlesix you only need to provide name attribute when referencing a block

Comment: Right!!! I just found another post here that ran into issues with my answer. I have since updated my answer with the correct xml. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to comment and say this still works as of Magento 2.3, it just solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the shorter version as well. For specific categories you can use seperate files: catalog_category_view_id_X.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection">
            <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: 's solution (using only the reference block and containing content) can also be added to Custom XML in the category if you don't want to make a custom layout file.

Comment: I definitely will proclaim this as the correct answer, HOWEVER, in some instances, product_list_toolbar (instead of category.products.list) will work, as I have just found out (after spending hours figuring it out) - presumably this can be due to upgrading from an older magento2 version (ie 2.3.2) meaning the incorrect reference block will be present.

Answer (score 1):

You have to referenceBlock `product_list_toolbar` as the `category.products.list` does not have `setDefaultDirection` method.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```