# Magento 2 "Layout Update XML" in Admin not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

I need to update sorting on just one category in our Magento CE 2.1.3 site.  I tried placing the following code in the Layout Update XML field on the category in the admin, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  If I put this same thing in an XML file in my theme it works like a charm, although it changes sorting throughout the whole site.

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
```

As an alternative, I know in Magento 1 you can put some category specific layout updates by category ID using the `<CATEGORY_123>`, so does Magento 2 have something similar?

---

**Update #1**

After testing the code above on a clean install I confirmed that it does indeed work.  I tracked it down to the fact that our theme is extending the `catalog_category_view.xml` file...

*app/code/design/frontend/`<vendor_name>`/`<theme_name>`/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml*

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

If I remove the `<action method="setDefaultDirection">` section, the "Layout Update XML" code I'm using in the admin seems to work great (only switching `asc` to `desc`, of course).  Is this expected behavior?  Does the extended theme file trump the Layout Update XML settings from the admin?

---

**Update #2**

Regarding my question for an alternative to the Magento 1 category id specific handle `<CATEGORY_123>`, thanks to [this link](http://sumankc.com/2016/12/10/different-template-for-different-categories-in-magento-2-category_id-layout-handle-in-m2/) I found that you can do this by using an ID specific file.  Instead of the global `catalog_category_view.xml` you can create a file called `catalog_category_view_id_123.xml` to update that specific category ID.

My question still stands, though, as to why the admin "Layout Update XML" field is ignored if you have a theme specific sorting set in an XML file.  It seems broken to me, but maybe it's expected behavior?

Answer (score 4):

**The code is working.**

I tried the code and it works fine on my magento 2.1.3 CE.

Make sure your `Design` tab looks like this:

[image]

What you can try:

1. Revert to developer mode.
2. Clear magento cache.
3. Clear browser cache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  You are right.  I tested on a clean install and it worked great.  I dug further and tracked it down to an extended layout file we have in our theme for `catalog_category_view.xml`.  I updated my question with further details since it still seems like there might be an issue... unless what I describe in the update is expected behavior.  Thoughts?