# how to change the product list Date 'asc >> desc'

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-list, magento2.2.4

how to change the product list Date 'asc >> desc'

Now is showing asc.

I want to change is desc is default >> ?product_list_dir=desc

using Magento Version 2.2.4

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to or create the following file

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Add following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Reference:** [Magento2: Default to sort by price descending not ascending](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/119829/48571)

Comment: sorry i can't see this file. are you using 2.2.4? @DineshYadav

Comment: you have to create this file if it doesn't exist in your theme.